# Java Bean/POJO design ambiguity

Tags: java

I am trying to assign value to a java bean property by manipulating other properties for which I had to write logic inside the getter method of the bean property. Is it correct from design perspective to do so ?

Comment: posting the code will allow others to understand

Answer (score 0):

If the getter/setter simply mirrors the value then there is no point in having them, or in making the value private. There is nothing wrong with making some member variables public if you have a good reason. If you are writing a 3d point class then having .x, .y ,.z public makes perfect sense.

Getters/setters are useful where there may be side effects, where you need to update other internal variables, recalculate cached values and protect the class from invalid inputs.

The usual justification for them, that they hide the internal structure, is generally the least useful. eg. I have these points stored as 3 floats, I might decide to store them as strings in a remote database so I'll make getters/setters to hide them, as if you could do that without having any other effect on the caller's code.

I think OOp basic principal is Encapsulation and information Hiding.

Encapsulation of behavior associated with getting or setting the property - this allows additional functionality (like validation) to be added more easily later.

Hiding the internal representation of the property while exposing a property using an alternative representation

So writing the validation logic inside setter and getter is fine...

Comment: I was worried about the design ....... but your answer was really helpful , thanks

Comment: Even in the case of a trivial 3d point class, it would be better to access them via gettes/setters, for example it becomes much easier to debug when exactly your x coordinate was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is perfectly fine.

You want to hide the logic of manipulating the member variables of that Bean/POJO object and encapsulate it. I don't know what exactly it is doing, but if it is only about the member variables of your Object, then it belongs to the setter/getter indeed.